# Local variable 'result ' value is not used even though I am assigning values to it, can any tell why is 'result' unused

Tags: python-3.x

my result variable is unused, even though I am assigning values to it, can any tell why is 'result' unused

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
    if speed in range(0, 61):
        result = 0
    elif speed in range(61, 81):
        if is_birthday == True:
            result = 0
        else:
            result = 1

    elif speed >= 81:
        if is_birthday == True:
            result = 0
        else:
            result = 2
    else:
        result = None

caught_speeding(60, False)
caught_speeding(65, False)
caught_speeding(65, True)
```

Comment: You are assigning to it, but you aren't using it. Maybe you forgot a `return result`?

Answer (score 0):

Modify to return the result:

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
    if speed in range(0, 61):
        result = 0
    elif speed in range(61, 81):
        if is_birthday == True:
            result = 0
        else:
            result = 1

    elif speed >= 81:
        if is_birthday == True:
            result = 0
        else:
            result = 2
    else:
        result = None
   return result
```